# Is it possible to target elements based on sibling ancestors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to use CSS to target an element that is a "cousin" of a specific element — in other words, where they are both descendants of sibling elements.

I can target an element based on its "uncle" or a sibling of an ancestor, like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2 data-section="name">Name</h2>
    <p class="hint">Full name of the employee</p>
    <p>
        <span class="value1">Joe Tester</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2 data-section="details">Occupation</h2>
    <p class="hint">Job role or title</p>
    <p>
        <span class="value1">Software Engineer</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 * element that
 *   has a class of value1
 *   and is a descendent of a p
 *     that is next to an h2
 *       with attribute data-section=name 
 */
h2[data-section="name"]~p .value1 {
  color: #F92759;
}
```

Result:

[image]

But what if the `data-section="name"` element is wrapped in another element?  Is it still possible to make the following HTML the same as the image above?

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2 data-section="name">Name</h2>
    </div>
    <p class="hint">Full name of the employee</p>
    <p>
        <span class="value2">Joe Tester</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**The practical application**: Targeting a node in a page (inside `body` tag) that has a particular `meta` element.

**Example JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nchaves/tefpY/**

Comment: Nope, not possible. Use more classes.

Comment: @Petah Did you read the practical application?  For reference, this is in user styles.  I am not in control of the HTML.

Comment: I wish this was possible. Life would be so much better, but as of now when it comes to CSS you can only go down (children) or in parallel (siblings). You cannot go up (parents) which seems to be your dilemma. I hope to one day in the near future revisit this question and see that the answer has been updated to something like this: (h2[data-section="name"] < div) ~ p .value1 (where '<' will mean parent) :)

Comment: There may be a CSS only work around. The question I have is, what is the exact context of this? That is, what _wraps_ the `div` elements that are around the "name" and "occupation" blocks and what other sibling elements are there to those two blocks, etc. What is the actual, _full_ html context that these appear in and how "static" or "dynamic" is that context? That would be the only way to determine if there is a CSS only work around using structural html selectors [like this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/tefpY/2/). But to get it precise, the structure must be known.

Comment: @ScottS I was thinking the purpose would be the same, but the actual context I'm most interested in is: `<html><head><meta name="condition"></head><body><div><span class="target"></span></div></body></html>`

Comment: So the "condition" may or may not be there, and when it is, you want the "target" to change. Yeah, with your actual html revealed and purpose revealed, I don't even see a CSS structural work around.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a css-only solution for this. You can, however, accomplish this using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("[data-section='name']").parent().parent().addClass('myclass');
</script>

<style>
    .myclass .value2 { color: #F92759; }
</style>
```

**JS Fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/tefpY/1/